# What's the best non-dp algo for knapsack?

Tags: knapsack-problem

I have an equivalent of knapsack problem where multiplication is substituted for addition. Can't find any algo for multiplication-type of problem, so naturally I switched to logarithms, but now I can't use dp-solution to knapsack. What's my best move? Thanks.